# SharePoint 2010 SP.UI.RTE IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range'

Tags: 2010, javascript, rte, chrome

Using Chrome, editing page layouts that contain HTML edit fields will not save any changes made via the edit page view. Hitting save just goes back to the page without the recent edits.

The error we are getting is `IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range'` from the SP.UI.RTE.js file.

Editing the page's properties from the Page Properties page works.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the error was (as the error states) a value being passed into the `setStart` and `setEnd` functions of the `Range` "class" that was out of range. (Not the RTE.Range "class")

The signature takes two parameters, a DOM object and an integer value. In my case the value 2 was over the bounds of range. Without spending much time, I wasn't able to figure out 100% where the larger value was coming from.

The solution I came up with was to write a wrapper around the `setStart` and `setStart` functions which takes the minimum of the `endOffet` and the integer passed in.

```
function spUIRTESetStartEndBugFix() {
        Range.prototype.setStartOld = Range.prototype.setStart; 
        Range.prototype.setStart = (function (a, b) { this.setStartOld(a, Math.min(b, this.endOffset)); });
        Range.prototype.setEndOld = Range.prototype.setEnd; 
        Range.prototype.setEnd = (function (a, b) { this.setEndOld(a, Math.min(b, this.endOffset)); }); 
};
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(spUIRTESetStartEndBugFix, "sp.ui.rte.js");
```